# Extending RxJava Observable in Kotlin with proper disposal

Tags: rx-java, kotlin

I'm trying to create a new operator for RxJava that works similar to `scan`, but can take two different types. This is similar to the traditional implementation of `fold` or `reduce` where if a default value is given, the arguments to the folding function can be of different types as long as the return type matches the accumulator.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
fun <T, R> Observable<T>.fold(acc: R, f: (R, T) -> R): Observable<R> = Observable.create { o ->
    var accm = acc
    subscribe({
        accm = f(accm, it)
        o.onNext(accm)
    }, {
        o.onError(it)
    }, {
        o.onComplete()
    })
}
```

I just subscribe to `this` inside an `Observable.create` block, and update the observer with new values put through the accumulator function. Problem is that the subscription won't be cleaned up when `this` is disposed. What should I do?

Comment: See `scan(R, BiFunction<R, T, R>)`: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#scan(R,%20io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction)

Comment: Hmm I thought I tried this, but it didn't work. Maybe my compiler was just complaining about something else. At any rate my particular function I was trying to implement wasn't really the focus of the question, it was just an example. I'd still like to know how I could do a similar type of extension just for a better understanding of how observables work. Thanks though!

Comment: There is a [wiki page](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Writing-operators-for-2.0) about writing operators.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: @akarnokd Hi!. Considering writing new post for your blog advance rx?